# SuperCollider error: ServerOptions.memSize not understood

Tags: memory, supercollider, livecoding

I ran into a memory error so I'm trying to allocate more memory to the server, as instructed by the IDE. However, it doesn't recognise the class method which is clearly documented. What could have possibly gone wrong??
There is absolutely nothing to my code, it's literally just

```
ServerOptions.memSize = 65536;
```

I've also tried what I found on a blog, which is

```
Server.options.memSize = 65536;
```

Which also does not work. Please help!! I want to make music!

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the current server, use the global variable 's'. Also, capitalization counts.

```
s.options.memSize = s.options.memSize * 2;
```